# How to call html file's javascript function with help of webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms. I am creating an app for android. I have a html file in which a java script function is placed. I placed the html file inside the Assets folder. The java script function returns some value that I need to use in my c# code.

I am using a webview and inside it I load the html file. Then with help of webview.Eval() method I am trying to call the javascript method. But unfortunately this method doesn't return value. It is void type.

Then I tried to use Android.Webkit.Webview and call the webView.EvaluateJavascript(function, new JavascriptResult()); method. But I am getting null value in result.

I am using following code:

```
Android.Webkit.WebView webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(GlobalClass.AndroidContext);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                 webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content/RSAGen2.htm");

                webView.EvaluateJavascript(function, new JavascriptResult());


public class JavascriptResult : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Webkit.IValueCallback
{
    public string Result;
    public void OnReceiveValue(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        string json = ((Java.Lang.String)result).ToString();
        Result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
        Notify();
    }
}
```

I am getting null value in result.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the value form javascript function with help of webview?

Regards,
Anand Dubey

Comment: did you check this out ,
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/

Comment: Thanks for reply... but I don't think it will help me. I need to call a javascript function that is placed in html file and need to get the return value.